# Android locationManager - "location not changed" event

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

I'm building a service that will let me know if the location hasn't change in a period of time for a certain amount of metres.

Then thing is I have the event `onLocationChanged` on my Listener.. but I don't know how to do the opposite.. that is, send a broadcast if the location is within the distance I provided after some minutes.

This is the code I have so far

**LocationService**

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

    public static final String LOC_INTENT = "com.xxx.intent.action.LOCATION";

    private Thread triggerService;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected MyLocationListener MyLocationListener;
    protected Criteria criteria;

    public static final int MIN_TIME = 300000; // 5 Minutes
    public static final long MIN_DISTANCE_MOTOR = 50; // 50 Metres

    private SharedPreferences settings;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {

        settings = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.settings_prefsName), 0);
        addLocationListener();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void addLocationListener()
    {
        triggerService = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    Looper.prepare();//Initialise the current thread as a looper.
                    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                    criteria = new Criteria();
                    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

                    final String PROVIDER = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                    updateLocation(getLastBestLocation(MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE_MOTOR));

                    MyLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE_MOTOR, MyLocationListener);
                    Log.d("LOC_SERVICE", "Service RUNNING! ("+PROVIDER+")");
                    Looper.loop();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, "LocationThread");
        triggerService.start();
    }


    public Location getLastBestLocation(int minDistance, long minTime) {
        Location bestResult = null;
        float bestAccuracy = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        long bestTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;

        List<String> matchingProviders = locationManager.getAllProviders();
        for (String provider: matchingProviders) {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (location != null) {
                float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
                long time = location.getTime();

                if ((time > minTime && accuracy < bestAccuracy)) {
                    bestResult = location;
                    bestAccuracy = accuracy;
                    bestTime = time;
                }
                else if (time < minTime && bestAccuracy == Float.MAX_VALUE && time > bestTime) {
                    bestResult = location;
                    bestTime = time;
                }
            }
        }

        return bestResult;
    }

    public static void updateLocation(Location location)
    {
        Context appCtx = MyApplication.getAppContext();

        double latitude, longitude;
        float speed;

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        speed = location.getSpeed();

        Intent filterRes = new Intent();
        filterRes.setAction(LOC_INTENT);
        filterRes.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
        filterRes.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
        filterRes.putExtra("speed", speed);
        appCtx.sendBroadcast(filterRes);
    }


    class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            if(settings.getBoolean("active", false))
                updateLocation(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should only be calling `requestLocationUpdates` once, and all your logic for receiving a location update should be in `onLocationChanged`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a timer for however long you want to test this. When it goes off, check if the last location you got in `onLocationChanged` is older than the timer length.

**EDIT**

Here is how I would imagine your service looking

Service starting

- [`requestLocationUpdates`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) called with appropriate minimum time and minimum distance that that you will be notified after
- Repeating task set where you check if an update was received (check out [`Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)

Service running

- Perform necessary actions when your timer goes off or `onLocationChanged` is called

Service stopping

- Remove location updates with [`removeUpdates`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.location.LocationListener%29)
- Stop your timer

Comment: is it a good practice if I create a new timer inside the onFinish method? so it will loop while the service is running?

Comment: I don't follow... what is the `onFinish` method? I will update my answer with an outline

Comment: Sorry I was using `CountDownTimer` instead of `Timer`. Works great. Thanks!